# Customizing TextField on tvOS using SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, tvos

I want to know what can I customize in TextField on tvOS. As far as I can see I can only change Title and button title a little using `SubmitLabel`

But, while looking at Settings interface I noticed that Apple made it a bit better. It contains description, different color for title/description, custom title for button and button is disabled when textfield is empty.

[image: Apple Settings TextField]

Is it possible to achieve any of these things what is seen?

I tried using inputAccessoryView from [Designing the Keyboard Input Experience](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/CreatingaGreatTextInputExperience.html) to add even another button and it works on UIKit, but it doesn't send any action on tap.

So my code looks like that right now

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("TitleKey", text: $text)
            .submitLabel(.continue)
    }
}
```

And I don't know how can I customize this view even further.

Comment: Try `SecureField` for passwords or just implement a UIKit view in SwiftUI

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI for Apple TV, `SecureField` and `TextField` has a limitation where it only accepts simple text as a label. Here is the documentation for SecureField:

```swift
public struct SecureField<Label> : View where Label : View {
```

To provide more detailed labeling or instructions, a practical workaround is to use separate `Text` views above the `SecureField` ***before*** entry. For instance:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 16) {
            Text("Apple ID Password")
                .font(.title3)
            Text("Enter the password for \"asda\".")
                .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                .padding(.bottom, 100) // Arbitrary number, might be better to size it with spacing
            SecureField(text: $text) {
                Text("Password")
            }
            .submitLabel(.continue)
            .frame(width: 600) // Arbitrary number, might be better to size it with spacing
        }
    }
}
```

This approach uses additional `Text` views for context, with customizable spacing and layout, effectively working around the `SecureField` label limitation.

[image]